# How to use custom Origin values in for internal repositories in Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall?

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, cloud-init, subiquity

OK, just working my way through integrating with autoinstall / cloud-init and finding all the incorrect ways that don't work.  :-) Looking at the following documents:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#apt
https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apt_source.html

...it would appear that the following `apt` snippet should work in our environment:

```
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
      - arches: [default]
        uri: http://my-custom-internal-mirror/ubuntu/internal
    package_upgrade: true
    package_update: true
    sources_list: |
      deb $PRIMARY $RELEASE main restricted universe multiverse
      deb $PRIMARY $RELEASE-updates main restricted universe multiverse
      deb $PRIMARY $RELEASE-security main restricted universe multiverse
      deb $PRIMARY $RELEASE-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    sources:
      mech-repo.list:
        key: |
          -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
<snip pubkey for brevity>
```

In our internal repo, we have some custom information in the 'Origin' and 'Label' fields of the InRelease file, which causes failures when machines are provisioned:

```
Repository 'http://my-custom-internal-mirror/ubuntu/internal focal InRelease' changed its 'Origin' from 'Ubuntu' to 'InternalInformation'
```

From another thread, I added `apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update` in `early-command`, but that doesn't seem to address the issue.  Any thoughts on how to get past this other than removing the additional information from our internal mirrors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue, but it's possible to overcome this with this setting:

```
conf: |
  Acquire::AllowReleaseInfoChange::Suite "true";
  Acquire::AllowReleaseInfoChange::Origin "true";
  Acquire::AllowReleaseInfoChange::Label "true";
  Acquire::AllowReleaseInfoChange::Version "true";
  Acquire::AllowReleaseInfoChange::Codename "true";
```

For more information, have a look [here](https://github.com/canonical/curtin/blob/master/examples/apt-source.yaml#L112).